# Is there any changes in Apple Push Notification service for ios 4, ios 5 and ios6?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

Hi i am new to Apple.

Are there any changes or difference between the push notification implementation for ios4, ios5 and ios6. If possible please provide any docs

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in implementation.